# Correct design of capsense controls

Tags: pcb-design, sensor, capacitive, touch-panel

I am trying to design a PCB with some capacitive controls. My first iteration did not seem to work well:

[image: Capacitive controls]
[image]

This was a 2-layer 1.6mm board with one circular control, and 5 buttons. The board is 48mm wide. The controller is a [CY8C5468LTI-LP026](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/microcontroller/legacy-microcontroller/legacy-8-bit-16-bit-microcontroller/psoc-5lp/cy8c54lpxxx/cy8c5468lti-lp026/). The controls were designed using the [Cypress Touch Controls in Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/cypress-touch-controls-ad).

The response from these sensors was very poor. One or two of them seemed to work OK, but there was a lot of interference between sensors, and a couple of them barely worked at all (even when looking at the raw signal).

I have seen recommendations for just about every possible way of laying this out, including a hatched ground plane under the sensors. No ground plane at all. Ground around the sensors.

My questions:

- Is there something obviously wrong with the PCB layout?
- Should I use the Cypress Touch Controls Altium Library, or should I do something else?
- Should I have used a hatched ground plane around the controls on the top layer?
- Should I have used a hatched ground plane on the bottom layer.
- Are the controls too big and too close to each other?